# Mysql insert data if not exist else show warning

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I need to check if value already exist in table and insert it if not exist, else i need to show alert about exception

Now i insert only data without checking

```
if(isset($_POST['new_ok'])){$result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO db1 (name) VALUES('".$name."')",$db);}
```

I trying do like that

```
if(isset($_POST['new_ok'])){if(mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT name FROM db1 WHERE name= '$name'");) != 0){$result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO db1 (name) VALUES('".$name."')",$db);}else{echo "wrong";}}
```

But `mysql_num_rows always` return 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this example

```
$sq="SELECT * FROM db1 WHERE username='$name'";
 $rsult=mysql_query($sq);      $count=mysql_num_rows ($rsult); 
if($count==1){echo "username already in use"; }

else 
 {//update statement here}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ERE name= '$name'");) != 0){$read
```

I think you should delete semicolon here.